# Сбитые стили в административной панели ларавел 10

Tags: laravel, orchid, административная-панель, laravel-10

Всем привет! Выполнил установку ларавела 10 (локальный Open Server), командой:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel orchid-laravel
```

Затем запустил установку orchid командами:

```
composer require orchid/platform
php artisan orchid:install
```

Установилась orchid 14.4.0. После чего создал пользователя админа. Вошел в админку, а там сбитые стили. Вся верстка поехала. Смотрю по путям использует файл:

```
/vendor/orchid/css/orchid.css?id=4dfe1560b70f26f308f7417938c848b1
```

для скриптов:

```
/vendor/orchid/js/manifest.js?id=fa18bd350409678078668239241217f5
/vendor/orchid/js/vendor.js?id=59c494b245e94ebd8ef3379d1b63a606
/vendor/orchid/js/orchid.js?id=b7ba9d4a2c391afae59075abb5f0a5f3
```

В папке vendor/orchid/ напрочь не вижу каталога css и js.
Выполнил команду

```
php artisan orchid:publish
```

В папке public появилась папка vendor со вложенными в нее стилями и скриптами, но при отображении страница админки все равно сбитая. Если в браузере правлю путь доступа к стилям и скриптам на следующие пути, то все работает.

```
/public/vendor/orchid/css/orchid.css?id=4dfe1560b70f26f308f7417938c848b1
/public/vendor/orchid/js/manifest.js?id=fa18bd350409678078668239241217f5
/public/vendor/orchid/js/vendor.js?id=59c494b245e94ebd8ef3379d1b63a606
/public/vendor/orchid/js/orchid.js?id=b7ba9d4a2c391afae59075abb5f0a5f3
```

Что я не так сделал? Как поправить верстку админки программно?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось костыльным. Скопировал папки

```
/public/vendor/orchid/css/
/public/vendor/orchid/js/
```

в `/vendor/orchid/`

И стили заработали.